# Is SignalR backplane necessary when using sticky sessions?

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-backplane, sticky-session

We have a multi-server, load-balanced environment for our application which uses sticky sessions.  We're considering adding a SignalR implementation to send updates to individual clients.  I've played around with SignalR a little bit so I'm aware of backplanes.  I'm wondering, since we're using sticky sessions, if we do not need to implement a backplane since a single server is handling user requests after authentication.

Comment: Depends on where the events come from. If only from the server that handles the user then there's no need for a backplane.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen What are some other examples of event sources besides the server?

Comment: For example if another server needs to send a message to that user. E.g. multiuser environment where users can interact and can be on different servers

Answer (score 1):

In your case, a backplane could be used to send messages to a user **regardless of which server** he's connected to.

I youn don't want to use a backplane, this means you will **only** be able to send updates to your client **from the machine they are connected to**, which means each server would have to check for user presence locally **before** sending a message.